# How to get one image to change to the image i click on using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to create a gallery using JavaScript.
I want to have a row of small images at the bottom and when you click on one it will display that image in a bigger window above. and that window currently contains and image.

New to JavaScript so not 100% sure what I'm doing.
here is what I was trying to use but wasn't working.
Any tips would be great thanks.:

```
<script>
function changeimage(val)
{
    var x = val.getAttribute("src");
    var y = getElementById("Display");
    var z = y.getAttribute("src");
    z.setAttribute("src","x");
}
</script>


<img class="mid_one" src="Images/home3.jpg" alt="home1" width="186px" height="186px" onclick="changeimage(this)"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

```
<img name="Display" id="Display" src="Images/home2.jpg" width="450" height="450" alt="Displayed Image"/>
```

edit: added display

Comment: Where and what is your element with the id "Display"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the attribute on the element (`y`), you can't set an attribute on an attribute value (`z`).

Also, you should use the variable `x` to get the source from the other image, not the string `"x"`.

```
var x = val.getAttribute("src");
var y = document.getElementById("Display");
y.setAttribute("src", x);
```

Comment: @Mikey: Sorry, it should of course be `document.getElementById`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ceFE2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function changeimage(val)
{
    var x = val.getAttribute("src");
    var y = getElementById("Display");
    y.setAttribute("src",x);
}
```

According to your logic  `var z = y.getAttribute("src");` is a string and `not an Element` .. In the next line you seem to set the attribute to the string ..